# How to change NSTimer's timeInterval dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The timeInterval of NSTimer is readOnly,we can not change it directly.Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue the timeInterval of NSTimer is readOnly so we can not change it directly.
The way to change timeInterval is redefine the timer,such as:

```
- (void)changeTimeIntervalWithInterval:(NSInteger)timeInterval{

if (self.timer) {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(printHH) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 } 
}
```